# hive External table maps to Azure Storage Authorization issue

Tags: hive, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

I am creating External table on hive which is mapped to Azure Blob storage

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test(id bigint, name string, dob timestamp,
>   salary decimal(14,4), line_number bigint) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION
>   'wasb://(container)@(Stroage_Account).blob.core.windows.net/test'

getting below exception

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got
>   exception: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException
>   com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to
>   authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header
>   is formed correctly including the signature.)

The Storage Account that i am using here is not primary storage account that is attached to hdinsight cluster

Could some one help me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue by adding configuration below, i have done this through Ambari server

**HDFS >>Custom core-site**
fs.azure.account.key.(storage_account).blob.core.windows.net=(Access
 Key)

fs.azure.account.keyprovider.(storage_account).blob.core.windows.net=org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.SimpleKeyProvider

**Hive >> Custom hive-env**

AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=(Storage Account name)

AZURE_STORAGE_KEY=(Access Key)